# JRebel monitoring class folder but not deploying

Tags: java, jrebel

While starting WL with JRebel  I can see folder monitor message but when placing class file into the folder its not being loaded.

Currently we have WL 9.2 which part of classpath is api.jar.

In addition we added to the classpath  classes folder  with same package structure of the api.jar.

In the root of the api.jar  we have the rebel.xml which pointing to the classes folder.

While starting the WL I can see its monitoring the classes folder but while placing any class file to the classes folder , JRebel not reloading it.

Please advice.

Comment: Did you try to use the class in your application? Just copying the class to the monitored folder doesn't necessarily reload it.

Comment: Yes, I run the flow , changes not getting loaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JRebel writes the classes it is making reloadable into the log with lines that contain this:
    instrumented class 'com.package.ClassName' from '/path1/com/package/ClassName.class'

If file change is detected then log contains line something like this
    Event 'CHANGE' on: '/path2/com/package/ClassName.class'

If path1 and path2 are same then upon next usage of the class the JRebel will reload the .class and print to log following
    Reloading class 'com.package.ClassName'

If path1 and path2 are not same then you must finetune your rebel.xml

This will get and idea of where the process breaks and where to continue looking.

Comment: Hi , The rebel.xml is defined as you described  but no luck. Its not reloading the class files

Comment: In this case can you send the jrebel.log to the support@zeroturnaround.com with the absolute location of .class file so it can be investigated further.

Comment: We found the issue was that the flow ran incorrectly so classes didn't get loaded. Thanks Margus.